# Simple c class compiled with gcov doesn't return during execution

Tags: code-coverage, gcov

I'm trying to use gcov and so I started to play with some small c class to test it.
The following class is the example.c I used

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
printf("Hello \n"); // I also tried without this printf
return 0;
}
```

For some reason after compilation in this way:

`g++ -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs example.c -o test`

when I try to execute it, the execution never return :-(

```
prompt> ./test
...   
...
...
```

This simple exe never return from his execution and of course the *gcda file is empty when I forced ctrl + c to terminate it.

Any Idea?
Thank you very much.

Comment: it works when I try it

Comment: the weird thing is that it works on a machine but when I try it on another machine I have this problem :-S I 'm a lot confused..  These machines should be equals

Comment: maybe try `strace ./test`

Comment: tks birdspider.. in fact for some reason it has some problem on fcntl:

mprotect(0x7f577fd32000, 32768, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x602000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f577ff6f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f577ff14000, 366624)          = 0
getpid()                                = 13273
open("/home/ex/example.gcda", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}

Comment: this might be helpfull to investigate - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lslocks.8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to wait for a write lock.

when I do `strace ./test 2>&1 | grep fcntl` i get

```
fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
```

according to http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl it has something to do with locking
(not an expert here)

Furher analysis show that it waits for lock on `test.gcda`. 
Do you have that open by something else ?

why I think that (follow the file-descriptor `3`):

```
<snip>
open("/home/<user>/test.gcda", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
<snip>
close(3)                                = 0
<snip>
```

Obviously it gets it on my machine.

Comment: no I haven't open it by something else.. instead I have also delete it and execute again the test but same result.. however yes it seems something like you wrote in your answer..